# 14.04 LTS apt-get segfault

Tags: apt, updates

Trying to update my web server, `apt-get update` produces this unhelpful error after reaching 99% while reading package lists at the end:

```
...
Ign http://mirror.rackspace.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US           
Reading package lists... Error!
```

If I attempt to install any software or run `apt-get upgrade` it merely prints `... 0%` and fails silently.

In dmesg, I see this worrisome line appearing with each attempt to update or upgrade:

```
[481989.865258] apt-get[17869]: segfault at ffffffffffffffff ip 00007f56e468fccb sp 00007fff4c83df10 error 5 in libapt-pkg.so.4.12.0[7f56e4639000+145000]
```

I'm not sure where to go from here!

EDIT: This appears to be a resources/memory issue on this server (512 MB virtual instance really should be bigger). Halting the IPython notebook server and repeating the apt commands was successful.

Comment: Ran into this same issue on Digital Ocean with a 512MB ram droplet. Restarting the server to free up some ram fixed the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I experienced the same problem and solved it with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure libapt-pkg4.12`

source: http://www.schakko.de/2013/08/11/fixing-segmentation-fault-in-libapt-pkg/

Answer (score 4):

It seems that your apt cache file  is corrupted.

Open terminal and run following commands.

- First  remove the cache file.

  ```
  sudo rm  /var/cache/apt/*.bin
  ```
- Now re-create it using

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get upgrade
  ```

Comment: +1 This should work great if the cache is indeed corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is there may be some disk corruption to the apt-get package! Can you try running `sudo apt-get install aptitude` and see what that does? If you can install aptitude, it works as an alternative to apt-get and you can also run `sudo aptitude reinstall apt-get` and see if it's able to repair apt-get! :)

Answer (score 0):

We ran into a similar issue and it was a VM that had been given too little memory.  Increasing RAM to 1G solved the issue for us.